# coffee cup tutorial has too strong reflections

Tags: light, transparency, color

I've seen this question asked before but the answers don't solve the issue.  I'm doing a blender tutorial by Blender Guru involving a coffee cup and donut. Part 4, Level 3: Realistic Liquid - Blender Beginner Tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdWUjEMzDhg

I'm having a problem with the glass not allowing the coffee color to pass through.  The top face is the brownish coffee color but the sides of the liquid take on the color of the base plane, as if the glass and the liquid are reflecting light from the plane very strongly. I'm thinking the glass should pick up some reflection but not so strongly as to prevent the coffee color coming through.  What can be causing this. I'm using blender 2.82 
see images below. I've resized the liquid to slightly overlap the glass so that's not it.  I also added a spoon to the scene at one point and it suffered from the same issue. The plane is reflected so strongly that it over powers the base colors.  I tried turning down the light which helps but the image becomes too dim.  I also tried lowering the alpha of the base plane which also helps but once again dims the entire image.

If I delete the plane the coffee color shines through ok, but the image is poorly lit then. see first image.

[image: coffee without plane below]

[image: coffee with plane below]

Comment: Hello :). What exactly is your question? Cycles render engine gives physically accurate results which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: The problem is that its not physically accurate. In real life the coffee color would clearly be seen through the lower half of the glass.  Here the blueness of the base plane is so strong as to prevent the coffee from being seen. All you see is blue. Even if I remove the glass and saucer and just view the liquid itself, suspended in space, the sides are heavily tinted with blue preventing the brown from showing at all. Like this.  https://isorepublic.com/photo/coffee-glass-cup/